# Как найти элемент в ArrayList<SomeClass> по условию для SomeClass?

Tags: java, классы, arraylist, java-8, indexof

Есть какой-то класс, в котором есть различные поля и т.д. Примерно так:

```
public class SomeClass{
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public SomeClass(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

И есть другой класс, в котором есть ArrayList с SomeClass в качестве типа:

```
ArrayList<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
list.add(new SomeClass("a", "a"));
list.add(new SomeClass("b", "b"));
list.add(new SomeClass("c", "c"));
list.add(new SomeClass("d", "d"));
```

Можно ли получить элемент, у которого getName() == "a", не перебирая весь ArrayList?

Простите, если что-то не так. Раньше я кодил только на JS и редко на php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, либо перебирайте в цикле и проверяйте, либо при помощи `Stream API`:

```
list.stream().filter(entry -> entry.getName().equals("a")).findFirst().get();
```

`findFirst` возвращает `Optional`, по-хорошему, перед вызовом `get` нужно проверить, не пустой ли результат. Или какой-то другой метод `Optional` использовать.

Важно: не используйте `==` для сравнения строк, для переменных объектного типа этот оператор сравнивает ссылки на объект.

Comment: Интересное решение, но что вы думаете  о HashMap

Comment: Что именно вы хотите сделать с HashMap? В вопросе ArrayList содержит объекты написанного вами класса. Можно дополнительно создать `HashMap<String, SomeClass>` для нужного вам отображения.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать HashMap
где Key - ключ для поиска, Value - значения связанное с конкретным ключом

```
   Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  // HashMap<Key, Value>

   map.put("a", "a");
   map.put("b", "b");
   map.put("c", "c");
   map.put("d", "d");

   map.get("a")
```

K getKey(): возвращает ключ объекта отображения

V getValue(): возвращает значение объекта отображения

Comment: Об этом я знаю и использовал до этого, но сейчас потребовалось переписать под ArrayList в связи с некоторыми ограничениями HashMap, такими как отсутствие чего-то вроде subList.